Table generated in quarto with gt_summary changes its format once as_gt is implemented
I am trying to create multiple tables in a pdf report using Quarto. In late 2023 the report and the tables were generated perfectly. However, I have now tried to use the same template and all the tables that have a as_gt() command get deformatted (at the header level). To be more specific, using a basic example, if I use the following command after loading the magrittr, gt and gtsummary packages:
mtcars %>%
  tbl_summary(by = cyl) 

I get a normal table when I run the code chunk and the same normal table if I render it. Basically this command allows me to use the gtsummary package to summarise the info in mtcars grouped by "cil". But if I then change my code to:
mtcars %>%
  tbl_summary(by = cyl) %>%
  as_gt() 

The table still renders normally if I run the chunk in R, but when I ask it to render to pdf, the formatting of the table's header completely changes, with the header becoming deformatted (pic below). Does anyone have any idea why this is the case? With other tables the width of the entire table is also affected.

The reason I need the as_gt() from the "gt" package is because I want to add specific formatting to the summary table. I have noticed that the same problem also happens if I use the command as_kable(), to convert the gtsummary table into a kable table. I have R version 4.4.1, latest Quarto and Tinytex up to date.

This looks like an issue with the latest update of gtsummary, e.g. the docs note that As of 2024-08-15, line breaks (e.g. '\n') do not render properly for PDF output. For now, these line breaks are stripped when rendering to PDF with Quarto and R markdown. (see ?as_gt). Not exactly your issue (i.e. in your case line breaks are added) but sounds related.

In the gtsummary v2.0 release, the default header in a tbl_summary() table was updated to include a \n linebreaker. I think the issue you're seeing is that the {gt} package does not recognize \n as a linebreaker for PDF output, and results in a malformed header. As a result, the gtsummary package will now strip \n from header rows when rendering to a gt table to PDF. Please install the most recent version of the package to ensure you have the fix mentioned by @stefan. My guess is that you're on gtsummary v2.0.0, and you need the newest release that addressed this issue.

Thx @DanielD.Sjoberg Was on 2.0.1. But the issue persists after updating to v2.0.2: https://i.sstatic.net/9nYaNNtK.png

Hi both, the issue was happening with version 2.0.1. I have now updated and rendered with version 2.0.2 but unfortunately it persists. Any suggestions on how best to proceed @DanielD.Sjoberg?

Following up on my comment above. The fix I mentioned above lives in the printing method for gtsummary tables. But when we call as_gt() explicitly, we skip the gtsummary print method, and instead the printing is handled via gt (which is why the line break fix is not present in your example). Here's how you can remove it, however.
mtcars|>
  tbl_summary(by =cyl)|>
  modify_header(all_stat_cols()~"**{level}** N = {n}")|>
  as_gt()


Thanks for reporting and I'll think on how/if I can migrate that fix from the print method into the as_gt() function.

Thanks Daniel, will implement that moving forward until some newer updates are out. Thanks for all the work you do on the package, it is my go to for summary tables and is incredibly useful!

FYI, this update is now in the dev version of gtsummary on GitHub. If it works for your way of working, you could install that version instead of updating any of your code.

That is great to hear, thank you for taking the time to provide this update!
